# react-native index.js not found issue on emulator

Tags: react-native

i m running below on mac.
react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.5

react-native run-android is successful.However when i am opening app in emulator (android) it keep showing me index.js not found issue however the file exist.[image]

Answer (score 0):

try putting the index.js on the same folder the package.json file is.